# foreignkey relationships

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

Lets say i have 3 classes, A, B, C.

```
class A(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=600, default="None")
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=CHOICES, name='rating')
    date = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='nonee')


class B(models.Model):
    Aname = models.ForeignKey('A', related_name='AB')
    classC = models.ForeignKey('C', related_name='BC')

class C(models.Model)
    #some info
        def average_rating(self):
        return self.?????.all().aggregate(Avg('rating')).values()[0]
```

How is it that I go from a view where my `self` is an object, all the way back to Class A so that I can aggregate the `rating` numbers. If i understand this correctly, the whole point of class B is just to be an object which shows relationships? I have been able to go between two classes, but when a third "relational" one is there i can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

When an operation needs to be performed on a recordset (queryset) basis rather than single record (model), then you should consider [custom managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers).

> Adding extra Manager methods is the preferred way to add “table-level” functionality to your models. (For “row-level” functionality – i.e., functions that act on a single instance of a model object – use Model methods, not custom Manager methods.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need class B at all. What you need is a ManyToManyField between A and C; that will, behind the scenes, create a table similar to B, but unless you actually need to add fields on that table you're better off not defining it explicitly.

Once you've added the M2M on C, your `average_rating` method can use it directly:

```
class C(models.Model)
    model_a_s = models.ManyToManyField('A')


    def average_rating(self):
        return self.model_a_s.all().aggregate(Avg('rating')).values()[0]
```

(Note, the title of your question is a bit confusing; there are no views involved here at all.)

Comment: i accidentally left the title from something else in there thanks. I will be adding other fields to class B. And I will have a another class D (and a few other) which will use all the basics of class A, and then I want to add on to class A with other fields also. I guess i just would like to know how to use a class which is part of another class. I think i should maybe research sub-classes?